# Java Desktop Application : How to fix height and width

Tags: java, swing, resize, netbeans-7, layout-manager

I am using Netbeans to develop a desktop application(SingleFrameApplication). When i run the application, I am able to resize it. I have set properties like : maximum size, minimum size and preferred size there but even then at run time it's resizeable. How can i fix it?

Comment: I am using Netbeans to develop desktop application. I think it uses jPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `JFrame`:

```
 frame.setResizable(false);
```

Inside an application class extending `SingleFrameApplication` the following will work:

```
 this.getFrame().setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to call "setResizable(false)" on a frame, etc.

See: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/AwtFrameNonResizable.shtml

Comment: this.getFrame().setResizable(false); This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When i run the application, I am able to resize it. .. How can i fix it?

Use layouts to make the main `JFrame` resizable. Then pack it, set a minimum size on the frame (equal to the packed size), and let the user have it at whatever size they prefer.

> I think it uses jPanel

I suspect that main class of the GUI would be a `JFrame`.  It is the `JFrame` that needs this action, as layouts often ignore the constraints on panels.

Comment: You are taking the overall wrong approach, but if you go that route, you should accept the answer of maksimov.  First 'correct' (according to the question) answer.